# neo4j backup error when backing up from ha cluster

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to setup backup for a Neo4j cluster with 3 instances. Neo4j is embedded.

If I run:

./neo4j-backup -from ha://10.106.4.80:5001,10.106.4.203:5001,10.106.14.164:5001 -to /tmp/neobak2/

from a host outside the 10.106.4.0 network, I get this error:

Could not find backup server in cluster neo4j.ha at 10.106.4.80:5001,10.106.4.203:5001,10.106.14.164:5001, operation timed out.

If I run it from a cluster member it works just fine. Also if I run the backup script with single instead of ha works fine from anywhere.

Below the basic cluster config I'm using:

`ha.server_id: 1
 ha.initial_hosts:10.106.4.80:5001,10.106.4.203:5001,10.106.14.164:5001 
 ha.tx_push_factor: 2`

I already checked for firewall issues, there aren't any. Neo4j version used is 1.9.5.
The webadmin interface shows the cluster has online backup enabled and listening to the default port.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) IP Adresses `10.0.0.0/8` are private. So I assume they're not routed from an external host.

Comment: That is true, but connectivity here is not an issue. I'm trying to run from within that network.

Comment: try to set `ha.cluster_server` explicitly